# How to cut out precise inside corners from hardboard?

Tags: woodworking

We are making some templates out of 1/8" hardboard for some stonework and trying to get them accurate to within 1/32" and it is very tricky.

The hard parts are the inside corners (some of the templates have an L-shape). On the outside we can just use a rail saw to get a precise cut, but we can't do that with the inside corners. Using a jigsaw results in a jagged, uneven cut.

Comment: I had a similar problem recently, so used a 4mm router bit and finished off with a wood file with metal 90 degree brackets on the outside corner as a template, to safeguard against over filing

Answer (score 1):

A couple ideas:

- Try different jigsaw blades. Many different tooth configurations exist, and some will work better with fibrous material.
- Use a circular saw set to full depth. The cut angle will be nearly 90°. Clamp guides to your workpiece if you don't feel steady. You can finish with a utility knife once you snap the remaining tip of the scrap, or overcut slightly on one face if that's not a problem.
- Use a rotary tool and a jig.
- Use your jigsaw, then clean up with a rotary tool and a straightedge (or just a utility knife).
- Finish the cut with a very sharp chisel. The flat (non-beveled) side should be against your final piece.